# Application is crashing while using pushmodal-async in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms and there is an option to provide searching in top bar. So we have taken a toolbaritems array and adding items one by one

but while double tapping on search icon the application is crashing. Crash indicating the below line

```
            ToolbarItems.Add (new ToolbarItem ("Info", Constants.SEARCH_ICON, () => Navigation.PushModalAsync (searchPage)));
```

and the error info showing:

System.InvalidOperationException: Page must not already have a parent.

--- Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double tapping would cause the `PushModalAsync` to happen twice, very quickly, causing an issue.

Instead, you might want to do something like this that prevents a double navigation and also correctly uses `await` on the `Task` returning method, `PushModalAsync`.

```
// Define a new variable
bool canNavigate = true;

ToolbarItems.Add (new ToolbarItem ("Info", Constants.SEARCH_ICON, async () => {

    if(canNavigate)
    {
        canNavigate = false;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync (searchPage)
        canNavigate = true;
    }

}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked for me. I am marking it as answer--Regards,Koushik Ganguly